# Ruby On Rails executing with wrong version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

I try to Run my new rails app using RubyMine, and it seems to use some wrong Ruby version and i can't figure out why!
I used rbenv to setup the environment
.ruby-version shows 3.0.2

> /bin/zsh -c "bash -c 'env RBENV_VERSION=2.7.2 /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv exec ruby /Users/ran/source/rails/MySite/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development'"
> Your Ruby version is 2.7.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.2
>
> ran@ran-mac MySite % ruby --version
> ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-darwin20]
> ran@ran-mac MySite %

What's wrong? I can not understand where it takes this 2.7.2 from!
Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're not using bundler? (`bundle exec` for example)

Comment: This is my first time trying to run a rails project, so no- there is no special reason for doing anything. I had some issues trying to run another project i downloaded, which led me to install different versions and now i'm trying to get my first project running again, with little luck

Comment: Use rbenv to manage your ruby versions and start your application from the terminal with `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: You can check which SDK is set for the project via Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Ruby SDK and Gems

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by changing the Ruby SDK, under Run\Debug Configurations to "Use other SDK: 3.0.2"
[image]